# TreeView loses virtualization with overridden control template

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview, virtualization, controltemplate

When I have the following TreeView in XAML (ItemsSource is set via code-behind to a long list of lists of lists):

```
<TreeView x:Name="Tree"
          VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
    <!-- ItemTemplate and ItemContainerStyle ommitted for brevity -->
</TreeView>
```

virtualization works just fine. However, when I tried overriding the TreeView's template, along with the inner ScrollViewer's template, virtualization disappeared. My template seems identical to the default, with the exception of a colored rectangle that I took out which was the entire motivation for redefining the template.

```
    <TreeView.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
            <ScrollViewer Focusable="False" 
                          CanContentScroll="True">
                <ScrollViewer.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition />
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />

                            <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" 
                                       Orientation="Vertical"
                                       Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                                       Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                                       Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                                       ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                                       Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" />

                            <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                                       Orientation="Horizontal"
                                       Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                                       Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                                       Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                                       ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                                       Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ScrollViewer.Template>
                <ScrollViewer.Content>
                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" />
                </ScrollViewer.Content>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

I've temporarily gotten around this by just making a transparent `SolidColorBrush` named `{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}` in the TreeView's resources, but I'd prefer to know what I've done incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. In the `ScrollViewer` template, the `ScrollContentPresenter` needs to have `CanContentScroll` set to its templated parent's value.

```
<ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                        CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A number of factors can break UI virtualization, sometimes when you don’t expect it:

1. Putting your list control in a ScrollViewer: The ScrollViewer provides a window onto
   its child content. The problem is that the child content is given unlimited “virtual”
   space. In this virtual space, the ListBox renders itself at full size, with all of its child
   items on display. As a side effect, each item gets its own memory-hogging
   ListBoxItem object. This problem occurs any time you place a ListBox in a container
   that doesn’t attempt to constrain its size; for example, the same problem crops up if
   you pop it into a StackPanel instead of a Grid.
2. Changing the list’s control template and failing to use the ItemsPresenter: The
   ItemsPresenter uses the ItemsPanelTemplate, which specifies the
   VirtualizingStackPanel. If you break this relationship or if you change the
   ItemsPanelTemplate yourself so it doesn’t use a VirtualizingStackPanel, you’ll lose
   the virtualization feature.
3. Not using data binding: It should be obvious, but if you fill a list programmatically—
   for example, by dynamically creating the ListBoxItem objects you need—no
   virtualization will occur. Of course, you can consider using your own optimization
   strategy, such as creating just those objects that you need and only creating them at
   the time they’re needed.

Comment: #1 seems like it could be relevant, but I'm not sure how I can solve for it. I tried setting the ScrollViewer's height to {{TemplateBinding Height}} (and the same for the grid inside the ScrollViewer) but no luck. As for #2, I did use the ItemsPresenter (as you can see) and even tried explicitly setting the ItemsPanelTemplate as @d.moncada suggested , but still no luck. I have to disagree with #3; I can clearly see the difference with and without virtualization, even when the ItemsSource is generated programmatically. The window won't even load when virtualization is off.